# logistic regression in matlab

Tags: matlab, logistic-regression

i would like to implement logistic regression in matlab, i have following  few code for this

```
function B=logistic_regression(x,y)

f=@(a)(sum(y.*log((exp(a(1)+a(2)*x)/(1+exp(a(1)+a(2)*x))))+(1-y).*log((1-((exp(a(1)+a(2)*x)/(1+exp(a(1)+a(2)*x))))))));
a=[0.1, 0.1];
options = optimset('PlotFcns',@optimplotfval);
B = fminsearch(f,a, options);

end
```

logistic regression is following :

first  we are calculating logit which is equal to

L=b0+b1*x

then we are calculating probability which is equal to
p=e^L/(1+e^L)

and finally we are calculating

y*ln(p)+(1-y)*ln(1-p)

i decided to write  all those stuff in one line,  but when i am running code , it gives me following error

```
>> B=logistic_regression(x,y)
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in fminsearch (line 200)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Error in logistic_regression (line 6)
B = fminsearch(f,a, options);
```

how can i  fix this problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to implement a logistic regression model, I usually call the `glmfit` function, which is the simpler way to go. The syntax is:

```
 b = glmfit(x,y,'binomial','link','logit');
```

`b` is a vector that contains the coefficients for the linear portion of the logistic regression (the first element is the constant term `alpha` of the regression). `x` contains the predictors data, with one row for each observation and one column for each variable. `y` contains the target variable, usually a vector of boolean (0 or 1) values representing the outcome.

Once you obtain the coefficients, you have to apply the linear part of the regression to your predictors:

```
z = b(1) + (x * b(2));
```

To finish, you must apply the logistic function to the output of the linear part:

```
z = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z));
```

If you need more tinkering on your data or on your output, and you require more flexibility and control over your model, I suggest you to look at this implementation:

https://github.com/mohammadaltaleb/Logistic-Regression

Comment: sorry what does n stand for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the answer because I was basing my assumptions on fitgml instead. By default, glmfit adds a first column of 1s to X, corresponding to the constant term in the model. So you don't have to do it manually. You can disable this default behavior by setting 'constant' parameter to 'off'.